# iOS 17 `viewAligned` ScrollView fast swiping skips views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I'm messing with the new ScrollView API for iOS 17 and have run into a small unexpected behavior with the `viewAligned` `scrollTargetBehavior`.

```
@State private var colors: [Color] = Array(repeating: [.red, .orange, .yellow, .blue], count: 100)

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
  LazyHStack(spacing: 8) {
    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { colors in
      color
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) { length, _ in
          length - 32 
        }
    }
  }
  .scrollTargetLayout()
  .padding(.horizontal, spacing)
  .padding(.trailing, 16)
}
.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
```

[image]

You'll notice that when I start faster, after a second the views start scrolling *rapidly*, scrolling past way more views than times I swiped. I was wondering if there was a way to disable this, so that the scroll view only swipes if I swipe, and doesn't automatically skip past certain views like in the gif.

Comment: You can set chage scrollTargetBehavior to ```.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)```

Comment: In this example, because the width of each view is not the width of the screen, that messes with the swiping